# XML parsing in Python with element tree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using Python with ElementTree to parse an XML file. I want to be able to make a list of dictionaries containing the information of all the CDs. I can use this list later to gather information, like displaying the title of CDs coming from the USA. The code below is working, but can easily be broken if the `YEAR` tag is not the last tag of CD. How can I rewrite this code so that tags could be in any order?

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

f = open("cd_catalog.xml")
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse(f)

catalog = []
cd = {}
for node in tree.iter():
    if node.tag != "CD" and node.tag != "CATALOG":
        tagtext = (node.tag,node.text),
        cd.update(tagtext)
    if node.tag == "YEAR":
        catalog.append(cd)
        cd = {}

for cd in catalog:
    if cd["COUNTRY"] == "USA":
        print("The cd named {0} is from USA".format(cd["TITLE"]))
```

2 entries of the xml file :

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to rewrite your XML parsing code is the following. In this this I define a generator which loops over all the `CD` elements of the root element (I do not check that this is a `CATALOG` element, although you could add that check in). This generator returns all of the sub-elements of each `CD` element as a dictionary.

The use of a generator is more efficient than building a dictionary of all the `CD` elements, particularly if your XML file is very large, since you only ever store a single `CD` element in memory.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def get_cd(element):
    try:
        for el in element.iter(tag='CD')
            yield get_cd_info(el)
    except AttributeError:
        # Python < 2.7
        for el in element.getiterator(tag='CD')
            yield get_cd_info(el)

def get_cd_info(element):
    return {'title':element.findtext('TITLE'),
        'artist':element.findtext('ARTIST'),
        'country':element.findtext('COUNTRY'),
        'company':element.findtext('COMPANY'),
        'price':element.findtext('PRICE),
        'year':element.findtext('YEAR')}
```

Here is the above method in action:

```py
s = '''<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
'''

e = etree.fromstring(s)

for cd in get_cd(e):
    if cd['country'] == 'USA':
        print('The cd "{0}" is from the USA.'.format(cd['title']))

# prints 'The cd "Empire Burlesque" is from the USA.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
....
for CD in tree.findall('cd'):
   for node in CD.finditer():
       print node.tag # TITLE, ARTIST, PRICE etc.

.....
```